Supabase: Querying a one-to-many inner join
I'm using Supabase as a database and trying to implement a query using the JS api.
My example setup is quite simple, I have two tables:
Children

| id | name      | parent_a_id     | parent_b_id  |

| 1  | Amy       | 1               |3             |

| 2  | Amanda    | 1               |3             |

| 3  | Alex      | 1               |2             |

Parents

| id | name      |

| 1  | John      |

| 2  | Jessica   |

| 3  | Juliana   |

My goal: Select all children who's parent_b is named Jessica.
My current approach (In this scenario only the row for Child Alex should be returned).
    let query = supabase
                .from('children')
                .select('
                        *,
                        parent_a:parents!inner(parent_a_id)(name),
                        parent_b:parents!inner(parent_b_id)(name)
                 ')
                 .eq('parent_b.name', 'Jessica');

This does not work. I get the following error due to the one-to-many relationship:
Could not embed because more than one relationship was found for 'Children' and 'Parents'
Does anyone have an approach on how to do this properly with the Supabase JavaScript SDK?

Did you get your answer? If yes Kindly share the approch to solve it.
